# Using the command "id" in Linux?

Tags: permissions, user-accounts, file-permissions, group-policy, acl

I have some doubts with the use of the command *id* in Linux...

I have added one user(andre) to the group "github-total", do if I do *id andre* I got:

```
$ id andre
uid=500(andre) gid=500(andre) groups=500(andre),502(github-total) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
```

But if I do only *id*:

```
$ id
uid=500(andre) gid=500(andre) groups=500(andre) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
```

The thing is that the user "andre" is not assuming that he is in the group "github-total" when I run only *id* without argument. And in reality the user is not in the group.

So my question is... How can I add the user "andre" to the group "github-total"?

Best Regards,

Sorry my english.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that you made the change but haven't logged out / logged back in again.

When you run id with no arguments, it prints the data inherited from the parent shell, which established the group IDs after it consulted the databases after login.

When you run id with a username, it instantly queries the databases to see what that user's group id information is.

So... to directly answer your question, logout then log back in.  :-)